# I need help with Duplicating on a mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a mac, and the mouse I use is an apple mouse that has no scroll key in the middle of it. Is there any way to duplicate items using my keypad or keyboard?

Comment: If you are talking about the apple magic mouse, it can be configured for the middle mouse button to work. Alternatively, you might be able to change the controls

Comment: It looks like this post has already been answered here:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171254/how-to-enable-middle-click-of-apples-magic-mouse

Answer (score -1):

Replace the Button 3 key with a key.
I think it's called Pick Block in the control menu.